# Is it possible to query all tables in a database along with primary key column and its max, min and count?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

This is the query I have now that can return results for one table at a time.

```
use *database_name*
select
'*dbo.table_name*' as Table_,
min(*primarykey_columnname*) Min_,
max(*primarykey_columnname*) Max_,
count(*) Count_
from *dbo.table_name*
```

I have this requirement in both SQL Server and PostgreSQL. It would be great help if you can help in solution for any of them.

Comment: Look at https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5554/sql-server-current-identity-value-report-for-all-tables/

Comment: How are you expecting to quantify the PK columns to accommodate a MIN and MAX function? Is it based on alphabetical order?

Answer (score 1):

You must do this with dynamic SQL. Assum that **ALL TABLES** have a unique column in the key definition...

For MS SQL Server :

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(max) = N''
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + N'SELECT ''' + KCU.TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + KCU.TABLE_NAME + ''' AS TBL, ' 
       + '''' + KCU.COLUMN_NAME + ''' AS PK, MIN("' + KCU.COLUMN_NAME + '") AS MIN_PK, '
       + 'MAX("' + KCU.COLUMN_NAME + '") AS MAX_PK, '
       + 'COUNT("' + KCU.COLUMN_NAME + '") AS NBR_PK FROM "' + KCU.TABLE_SCHEMA + '"."' + KCU.TABLE_NAME + '" UNION ALL '
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS AS TC
       JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS KCU
          ON TC.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = KCU.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA AND TC.CONSTRAINT_NAME = KCU.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE  TC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY';
SET @SQL = LEFT(@SQL, LEN(@SQL) - 10);
EXEC (@SQL);
```

Esay to adapt to PG... But will be much verbose !